# Finding subsequence (nonconsecutive)

Tags: python, string

If I have string `needle` and I want to check if it exists contiguously as a *substring* in `haystack`, I can use:

```
if needle in haystack:
    ...
```

What can I use in the case of a non-continuous *subsequence*? Example:

```
>>> haystack = "abcde12345"
>>> needle1 = "ace13"
>>> needle2 = "123abc"
>>> is_subsequence(needle1, haystack)
True
>>> is_subsequence(needle2, haystack)  # order is important!
False
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't know if there's builtin function, but it is rather simple to do manually

```py
def exists(a, b):
    """checks if b exists in a as a subsequence"""
    pos = 0
    for ch in a:
        if pos < len(b) and ch == b[pos]:
            pos += 1
    return pos == len(b)
```

```
>>> exists("moo", "mo")
True
>>> exists("moo", "oo")
True
>>> exists("moo", "ooo")
False
>>> exists("haystack", "hack")
True
>>> exists("haystack", "hach")
False
>>>
```

Comment: I like that this has linear time complexity

Comment: `exists("haystack", "")` returns True. Add `if len(b) == 0: return False` to the answer

Comment: @pouya In my opinion, it is quite correct for `exists("haystack", "")` to return True.

Answer (score 20):

Using an iterator trick:

```
it = iter(haystack)
all(x in it for x in needle)
```

This is only a concise version of the same idea presented in [tobias_k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29954930/674039).

Comment: For anyone else who tries to inline `it`, that is, tries to do it one line like: `all(x in iter(haystack) for x in needle)`, it doesn't work because `iter(haystack)` is re-instantiated each time.

Comment: This implementation is **in average 1000 times faster** than @Ishamael implementation

Comment: This should be the best answer - concise and elegant!

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility: You can create iterators for both, needle and haystack, and then pop elements from the haystack-iterator until either all the characters in the needle are found, or the iterator is exhausted.

```
def is_in(needle, haystack):
    try:
        iterator = iter(haystack)
        for char in needle:
            while next(iterator) != char:
                pass
        return True
    except StopIteration:
        return False
```

Answer (score -1):

We can try simple for loop and break method and pass on substring once the match is found

```
def substr(lstr,sstr):
lenl = len(lstr)
for i in sstr:
    for j in range(lenl):
        if i not in lstr:
            return False
        elif i == lstr[j]:
            lstr = lstr[j+1:]
            break
        else:
            pass
return True
```