# How to check if an element in a list comes from after a given element

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, sequence

I have a list and want to check if a given sequence exist in the list or not.
 For example the given sequence is `'a','h','z'` and the list is `l = ['a','b','h','g','z']`. Given that in the list z comes after h after a, I need the code returns True value.

```py
def check_for_a_h_z(seq):
    return ('a','h','z') in zip(seq, seq[1:], seq[2:])
```

The code return true if only `'a','h','z'` are coming exactly after each other.

Comment: I'm a fan of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52709319/2336654)  From that question referenced as the dup target.  It works for strings, list of characters, list of strings.

Answer (score 3):

Back of the envelope brute force attempt at a generic solution for two sequences:

```py
from typing import Sequence

def ordered_contains(s1: Sequence, s2: Sequence) -> bool:
  '''
  >>> ordered_contains('ahz', 'abhgz')
  True
  >>> ordered_contains('', 'asdlkjf')
  True
  >>> ordered_contains('lol', 'lofi')
  False
  '''
  i = 0
  for v in s1:
    try:
      i = s2.index(v, i)
    except ValueError:
      return False
  return True
```

Comment: please run an example

Comment: @user10316146 OK, I've included [doctests](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/doctest.html) to show the example you asked for.

Comment: neat - O(n) at most?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I think if n=len(s1) and m=len(s2), then it's Θ(n+m). Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm sloppy with algorithm complexity.

Comment: I suppose `if len(s1) > len(s2): return False` would be a trivial optimization, but I'm not putting it in for SO aesthetic reasons. :)

Comment: if nothing of s1 in in s2 it will search all of m, if there is anything of  s1 in s2 it will search incrementally m also up to its maximum (if not found) or less (if found) - due to storing the last found index it is never re-searching over visited stuff in s2 - so I think it can not be more then m at most

Comment: @PatrickArtner The worst case is when all but the very last element of s1 is in s2, but the last one is not, right? In which case we iterate over all of s1 and also walk all of s2. For each step through s1, we scan at least one element of s2, up to len(s2). That's why I still think it's worst case Θ(n+m).

Comment: You've convinced me. I agree that the worst case runtime is Θ(len(s2))

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it with recursion:

```
def list_sequence_recursive(test, lst):
    if len(test) == 1:
        return test[0] in lst
    else:
        if test[0] in lst:
            idx = lst.index(test[0]) + 1  # don't send the matched element
            return list_sequence_recursive(test[1:], lst[idx:])
        else:
            return False

test_sequence_recursive(['a', 'h', 'z'],
                        ['a','b','h','g','z'])
# True
```

Note we use `lst.index(test[0]) + 1` for the next iteration's starting index so that we only send elements *after* the one that was matched. If you leave off the `+ 1`, you would erroneously match your input list with, say `['a', 'a', 'h']` even though you only have one `'a'`.

For your example, this would:

1. find `'a'` and then call itself with the arguments `['h', 'z']` and `['b','h','g','z']`
2. find `'h'` and then call itself with the arguments `['z']` and `['g', 'z']`
3. find `'z'` and return `True` up the chain

Answer (score 2):

This will return `True` if *`things`* is somehwere in order in *`seq`* in `O(n)` worst case:

```
def check_for_things(things,seq):
    k = things[:]
    for c in seq:
        if c == k[0]:
            k.pop(0)
        if not k:
            break

    return not k  # if you popped all from k you are done

print( check_for_things(list("ahz"), list('abhgz')))
print( check_for_things(list("ahiz"), list('abhgz')))
```

Output:

```
True  
False
```

It will also produce `True` for  `list("ahz"), list('abhhhhhhhhhhgz')` - the superflous `h` are ignored.

---

A more optimized solution (suggested by [@Aran-Frey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222951/aran-fey)) would be using [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) - popping elements anywhere then the end of a `list` is costly because the whole remaining `list` data is shifted over by 1 - deque can `popleft` (and `popright`) in O(1):

```
def better_check_for_things(things,seq):
    k = deque(things)
    for c in seq:
        if c == k[0]:
            k.popleft()
        if not k:
            break

    return not k  # if you popped all from k you are done

print( better_check_for_things(list("ahz"), list('abhgz')))
print( better_check_for_things(list("ahiz"), list('abhgz')))
```

Comment: This is how I thought to do it

Comment: If you're gonna do `k.pop(0)`, I'd recommend using a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) instead of a list.

Comment: @Aran-Fey popping from the front of the list is costly, agreed. Added a deque version.

Answer (score -1):

A somewhat intuitive way to do it, but not very Pythonic:

```
l=['a','b','h','g','z']

def check_for_a_h_z(seq):
    if 'a' in seq:
        ind=seq.index('a')
        if 'h' in seq[ind:]:
            ind2=seq.index('h')
            if 'z' in seq[ind2:]:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False


check_for_a_h_z(l)
```