# How to check if a list is a subsequence of another list in order

Tags: python, list

I have a list `input`:

```
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 8, 3, 8, 5, 8, 5, 9, 5, 7, 5, 7, 4, 9, 7, 5, 7, 4, 7, 4, 7, 8, 9, 7, 5, 7, 5, 4, 9, 3, 4, 8, 4, 8, 5, 3, 5, 4, 7, 3, 7, 3, 1, 2, 7, 1, 7, 2, 1]
```

I need to check if the elements of a `lookup_list` `[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,5,4,3,2,1]` are present in the above list in a spread out manner in the same sequence.

This will illustrate what I am trying to say:

[**1**, ***2***, 4, ***3***, 5, 7, 5, 3, 8, 3, 8, 5, 8, 5, 9, 5, 7, 5, 7, ***4***, 9, 7, ***5***, ***7***, 4, 7, 4, 7, ***8***, ***9***, 7, ***5***, 7, 5, ***4***, 9, ***3***, 4, 8, 4, 8, 5, 3, 5, 4, 7, 3, 7, 3, 1, ***2***, 7, 1, 7, 2, ***1***]

The numbers in bold are the numbers from the `lookup_list` present in the **same order** in the `input` list, but with other irrelevant items in between as well.

Is there any way I can check for this?

This is the method I tried:

```
count = 0
a = 0
indices = []
for item in list:
    idx = -1
    if count < len(input_list):
        idx = list.index(input_list[count])
        if idx != -1:
            a = a +len(list[:idx])
            list = list[idx:]
            indices.append(a + idx)
    count = count +1
print(indices)
```

but it gave me the following result:

```
[0, 2, 5, 35, 25, 24, 33, 30, 33, 37, 38, 64, 54]
```

The issue is, the order of the `lookup_list` is not maintained in this method.

Comment: what is your question exactly? "Is there anyway I can check for this?"?

Comment: Seems like it’s well explained: how to determine sequence equality while skipping non-common elements. That said.. this can be done with nested loops: have any work started? Just repeat the steps to solve it “by pen and paper”. How would this pen and paper algorithm be explained in words / bullet point steps?

Comment: Hi @deadshot, yes, user2864740 is right, I would like to know if there is any way I can check for the items from lookup_list in the input list, while skipping non relevant elements and maining the sequence order from the lookup_list.

Comment: Can you think of a step-by-step process you would follow by hand to test for it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an iterator over your input list.  Call `next` to get each value.  If you exhaust the iterator without finding all the matches, you will get a `StopIteration` and then you would return `False`.

```
def check(input_, lookup_list):
    it = iter(input_)
    try:
        for i in lookup_list:
            # read values from the input list until we find one which 
            # matches the current value from the lookup list
            while next(it) != i: 
                pass
        # we found matches for everything on the lookup list
        return True
    except StopIteration:
        # we tried to go past the end of the input list
        return False
```

Comment: List iterators support `in` as well, and `all` short-circuits, so you can reduce this to `return all(i in it for i in lookup_list)`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks. I see that this question was later marked as a duplicate of a question which has an answer to that effect - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52709319/13596037

Answer (score 1):

```
def check_exists(l, lookup_list):
check = True
for i in lookup_list:
    try:
        index = l.index(i) 
        l = l[index+1:]
    except ValueError:
        check = False 
        break 
return check
```

**check_exists()** function will accept the complete list and lookup list as arguments and returns you True if sequence exists or false if doesn't .

Here is the full program -

```
def check_exists(l, lookup_list):
    check = True
    for i in lookup_list:
        try:
            index = l.index(i) 
            l = l[index+1:]
        except ValueError:
            check = False 
            break 
    return check



l = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 8, 3, 8, 5, 8, 5, 9, 5, 7, 5, 7, 4, 9, 7, 5, 7, 
4, 7, 4, 7, 8, 9, 7, 5, 7, 5, 4, 9, 3, 4, 8, 4, 8, 5, 3, 5, 4, 7, 3, 7, 3, 1, 
2, 7, 1, 7, 2, 1]
lookup_list = [2,3,4,5,7,8,9,5,4,3,2,1] 

print(check_exists(l,lookup_list))
```

Comment: I like the idea of using `l.index` -- and what you have will clearly work -- but instead of constructing a new, shorter list each time, you could exploit the fact that `l.index` takes an optional second argument which is the starting index, and use the value of `index` saved from the previous time -- that is `index = l.index(i, index) + 1`. (Initialise `index` to 0.)

Comment: It makes sense Alaniwi. I will change it. Thanks

Comment: @SindhuSatish brother Don't forget to update it as alaniwi commented

Answer (score 0):

The most trivial way is to convert the first list (do *not* call it `input`!) to a string (the angle brackets keep multi digit numbers "together"):

```
input_str = "".join("<"+str(i)+">" for i in input_list)
```

Convert the second list to a regular expression that allows optional additional items between the required items:

```
lookup_str = ".*" + ".+".join("<"+str(i)+">" for i in lookup_list) + ".+"
```

Now, check if the input string matches the regular expression:

```
if (re.search(lookup_str, input_str)): # there is a match
```

Comment: nice idea, so the pattern does not need brackets as in `"[.+]".join` ?