# Why should I convert iterable object to iterator first?

Tags: python, iterator

I have seen the code in `heapq.nlargest()` of Python standardlib as following:

```
if n == 1:
    it = iter(iterable)
    sentinel = object()
    if key is None:
        result = max(it, default=sentinel)
    else:
        result = max(it, default=sentinel, key=key)
    return [] if result is sentinel else [result]
```

It convert `iterable` to `it` by `iter()` first, and then to get maximum value from `it` by `max()` function passed argument `it`.

Why don't just use iterable object? Are there any advantage I have no awareness?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the current code, there is no advantage. The line could be safely removed, just passing `iterable` into `max` directly.

I think this is just a remnant of an earlier implementation, which used `islice`:

```
# Short-cut for n==1 is to use max() when len(iterable)>0
if n == 1:
    it = iter(iterable)
    head = list(islice(it, 1))
    if not head:
        return []
    if key is None:
        return [max(chain(head, it))]
    return [max(chain(head, it), key=key)]
```

This is from [18e9512](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/18e9512cce5e42bd982cc08c2f4b05b6c566bb01#diff-20c05f9dced85dbcf10ab607da01e8bfR395-R403). Taking an explicit iterator was not removed in a later optimization, although it could have been, i.e. [277842e](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/277842eff12eba1ceeeba1cee93db3ec99d5c95a#diff-20c05f9dced85dbcf10ab607da01e8bfL490-R422).

For a good example of when it *is* useful to convert an iterable into a consumable iterator first, take a look at the question [**Finding subsequence (nonconsecutive)**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29954748/674039)

Answer (score 3):

There is no advantage to `it = iter(iterable)` in the code shown and that line should be removed. `max` calls `iter()` (or the C equivalent) on the first argument making the original call completely redundant.

There are cases where it is useful, such as an iterator that is only partially consumed in several steps. In a wildly contrived example, you may want the first value and then everything after 3. This demonstrates using `next` to get a value, a `for` loop to consume more and finally passing to another function/class to consume whatever is left over. Note that `next` would raise `StopIteration` if there were no values, but the other two work fine even if the iterator has been exhausted.

```
iterable = [1,2,3,4,5]
it = iter(iterable)
first = next(it)
for x in it:
    if x == 3:
        break

final = list(it)
print(first, final)
```